# Meaning of a conjugation of 巡らす (巡らせ)

Tags: nuances, renyōkei

This is from a light novel I'm reading. Here's the part that I'm having trouble with this sentence:

> オレは痛みを訴える頭を巡らせ

Based on what I know regarding the rest of the sentence, I believe that this translation should be something like:

> I developed a headache as I thought it over.

According to my electronic dictionary, 巡らせ should be the imperative form of 巡らす.  But I'm having trouble reasoning out why the imperative would be needed here since he's thinking it over himself and not being commanded by someone else to think it over.

If you need more context, here's the passage that I'm looking at:

> どうして、こんな事になったのだろう……。
>
> オレは痛みを訴える頭を巡らせ、こうなってしまった原因を思い返した。

Comment: Hello and welcome to Japanese.SE! Where is this sentence from? Somebody inserted a typo (or OCR error) into the first character...

Comment: Ah, correct.  It should be "ore".  The sentence comes from a light novel that I'm reading.  I didn't catch the transcription mistake because of the font that I'm using.

Comment: 巡らせる's imperative form is 巡らせろ・巡らせよ・巡らせい.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「オレは[痛]{いた}みを[訴]{うった}える[頭]{あたま}を[巡]{めぐ}らせ」

「巡らせ」 is **not** in the imperative form.  Rather, it is the [連用形]{れんようけい} (continuative form) of the causative verb 「巡らせる」.

「頭を巡らせる」 is a set phrase meaning "to ponder".

> "I pondered in my aching head, trying to recall the cause as to why this had to happen."